# Extended Fermat's Last Theorem

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

It is well known that for all $n>2$, there is no integer solution for the following:

$$x^n + y^n = z^n $$

I will modify this equation slightly. What if the number of terms on the left-hand side is equal to $n$? For instance $n=5$:

$$a_{1}^{5}+a_{2}^{5}+a_{3}^{5}+a_{4}^{5}+a_{5}^{5}=+a_{6}^{5}$$

Is there solution for such equations, where the $a_k$'s are integer? (I mean non-trivial)

Comment: There is always a solution with $a_i=0$, for $i=1,\ldots, n-1$ and $a_{n}=a_{n+1}$. These are trivial solutions. So there *are* integer solutions for $x^n+y^n=z^n$ for all $n>2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have the following non-trivial solution
$$
72^5=19^5+43^5+46^5+47^5+67^5.
$$
Here $72$ is the smallest positive integer with this property. For more examples see [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation5thPowers.html). In general, [Euler's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture) is about your equation. It was disproved for $n=4,5$ but is still open for $n\ge 6$.

Comment: I marked this as accepted answer. Because what I am looking for was whether the conjecture exists.

Comment: In the simplest FLT case with power three you have only n-1 nth powers adding up to another one. Here you have n numbers. So you have c n^5 sums less than n^5.